App deployed on AWS EC2 instance: How can I get my react container to communicate with my springboot container using the internal URL?
I have two docker containers running on a ubuntu EC2 instance. The client is built and run using docker build and docker run. The springboot/postgres docker is a docker compose. The client has ports 14174:4173. The springboot/postgres has 18080:8080. The VPC for the instance has two security groups (default and launch-wizard-1). Both have ports 8080 and 18080 allowed.
IPv4 Custom TCP TCP 8080 0.0.0.0/0 allow 8080
IPv4 Custom TCP TCP 18080 0.0.0.0/0 allow 18080
These may be redundant because I also have this:
IPv4 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 all traffic
I am only using http (not https) for now.
I can hit the react/vite client with the public URL on 14173 from my local PC. I can also hit the springboot on 18080 with the public URL (I'd rather not be able to going forward).
The .env file in the client docker has the VITE_SERVER_API_URL. If I set this to the internal URL on 18080 or localhost on 18080 the client can not hit the springboot (no data loads and the springboot log shows no interaction). But if I set it to the public url on 18080 the client can it the back end.
How can I set this up so that the client can reach the springboot using the internal URL?
Edit - here is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  react-app:
    image: setlist-frontend
    build:
      context: ./setlist-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 14173:4173
    container_name: react-client
    links:
      - spring-boot-app

  spring-boot-app:
    image: setlist-backend
    ports:
      - 18080:8080
    build:
      context: ./setlist-backend
    container_name: spring-boot-app
    depends_on:
      - setlistdb
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://setlistdb:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  setlistdb:
    image: postgres:14.12-alpine
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    container_name: setlistdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - setlistdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

volumes:
  setlistdb:
  setlistdata:
    external: true

And in ./setlist-frontend, the .env has just one line:
VITE_SERVER_API_URL=http://spring-boot-app:8080


by default docker containers are isolated from each other unless they are on the same docker network. for your client container to reach the springboot container using an internal url, both containers need to be on the same docker network.
and by the  way referencing localhost from inside the container references itself not the host or other container.
therfore you need to set VITE_SERVER_API_URL=http://springboot-containername:internal-port in you .env of client

Thank you for your reply @nabin !
Just checking:
This is my springboot container info from docker ps:
bcc8b557384b   walmsleyj/setlist-backend   "java -jar /app.jar"     20 hours ago     Up 20 hours     0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp, :::18080->8080/tcp   spring-boot-app
This is what I have in .env now:
'VITE_SERVER_API_URL=http://spring-boot-app:18080'
But the client is still not reaching the spring-boot-app. Have I misunderstood?

@JimWalmsley did you set VITE_SERVER_API_URL=http://spring-boot-app:8080 and checked both the containers are in same network ??

Thanks @nabin.
I have included the react client container in the same docker compose file with the spring-boot-app and the postgres db. These containers are all on the default network.
I have checked that they are really on that network using docker inspect.
So the client should be able to reach the spring-boot-app using
VITE_SERVER_API_URL=http://spring-boot-app:8080
in the same way that the spring-boot-app can reach the db using
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://setlistdb:5432/postgres.
I have tried using my own network setup but that didn't help.

ah ok can you please paste your docker compose file here, i think i got what your issue is. I just want to know how you are setting VITE_SERVER_API_URL for client container , this env varaible should be availeable to the cleint container duing the build. is your client container getting built with this env var during its build.

Thanks @nabin, I have added that information in an edit above.
